# implode multidimensional php array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working on e-commerce site in php. I've multidimensional php array like this :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 7
    )
```

)

I am working on Advance search option. I've two table first one is product and another one is productattributes. I want to implode zero index array value by OR operator, One Index array value by `OR` Condition and then final array with zero index AND first index like this :-

```
select * from tbl_product where id IN(select product_id from tbl_vehicleproductequipments where (equipmentvalue_id = 1 OR equipmentvalue_id = 2 OR equipmentvalue_id = 3 OR equipmentvalue_id = 4) AND (equipmentvalue_id = 5 OR equipmentvalue_id = 6 OR equipmentvalue_id = 7)
```

I've tried this code :-

```
$eqpcond = "";
    if(!empty($_REQUEST["equipmentarr"])){
        foreach($_REQUEST["equipmentarr"] as $y => $equipval){
            $eqpcond = "select * from tbl_product where id IN (select product_id from tbl_vehicleproductequipments where ";
            foreach($equipval as $s => $vl){
                $equipcarr[] = " OR equipmentvalue_id = $vl";
            }
        }

        if(!empty($equipcarr)){
            $eqpcond = implode(" AND ",$equipcarr).")";
        }
    }
```

and i got the query like this which is not correct.

```
select * from tbl_product where id IN(select product_id from tbl_vehicleproductequipments where equipmentvalue_id = 1 AND OR equipmentvalue_id = 2 AND OR equipmentvalue_id = 3 AND OR equipmentvalue_id = 4 AND OR equipmentvalue_id = 5 AND OR equipmentvalue_id = 6 AND OR equipmentvalue_id = 7)
```

Please help me as I got stuck in this situation and I don't know how to do this. Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: don't use sub query like this `IN(SELECT....)`, you can get them in an array and make a join variable then use it.

Comment: Can u please write code of it. I know only this way.

Comment: This part doesn't make sense: `...(equipmentvalue_id = 1 OR equipmentvalue_id = 2 OR equipmentvalue_id = 3 OR equipmentvalue_id = 4) AND (equipmentvalue_id = 5 OR equipmentvalue_id = 6 OR equipmentvalue_id = 7)`. equipmentvalue_id can't be one of those two groups of values at the same time.

Comment: make a different query for subquery and fetch them, collect them into an array then `$in = join(", ", $fetch_arr);`

Comment: There are multiple equipments for a particular product so equipmentvalue_id can be one of these values at same time

Comment: @Tani, You must check my answer, no need to accept, just check the way you ca also did this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..I thinks this will produce the desired query. If not, please post the generate query and will make necessary changes.

```
$eqpcond = "";
        if (!empty($_REQUEST["equipmentarr"])) {
            foreach ($_REQUEST["equipmentarr"] as $y => $equipval) {
                $equipcstr = "";
                $equipcarr = array();
                $eqpcond = "select * from tbl_product where id IN (select product_id from tbl_vehicleproductequipments where ";
                foreach ($equipval as $s => $vl) {
                    $equipcstr .= " OR equipmentvalue_id = $vl";
                }
                $equipcstr = trim($equipcstr, 'OR');
                $equipcarr[] = $equipcstr;
            }

            if (!empty($equipcarr)) {
                $eqpcond = implode(" AND ", $equipcarr) . ")";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for Your Kind Reply but using this code i am able to join the first array index value only zero index value is not coming. The output of the above code is :-
select * from tbl_product where id IN(select product_id from tbl_vehicleproductequipments where equipmentvalue_id = 5 OR equipmentvalue_id = 6 OR equipmentvalue_id = 8)

Comment: Ohh Sorry...my mistake.. just place the `$equipcarr = array();` immediately after the `if (!empty($_REQUEST["equipmentarr"])) {` and see what happens

Comment: Its working fine. Thanks very much for your kind reply. I am accepting this as answer. Thanks very much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks..glad to help

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I don't think you have a valid query, `where equipmentvalue_id 
>   IN (1,2,3,4) AND equipmentvalue_id IN (5,6,7)` How it is possible?

Check it out: [Online test](https://3v4l.org/4lp9c)

This is your desire solution, using some implode function..

```
$arr = array(
        array(1, 2, 3, 4),
        array(5, 6, 7)
    );
```

**Subquery using *OR***

```
$sql = 'select product_id from tbl_vehicleproductequipments where (equipmentvalue_id = '.implode(" OR equipmentvalue_id = ", $arr[0]).') AND (equipmentvalue_id = '.implode(" OR equipmentvalue_id = ", $arr[1]).")";
```

**Subquery using *IN***

```
$sql = 'select product_id from tbl_vehicleproductequipments where equipmentvalue_id IN ('.implode(",", $arr[0]).') AND equipmentvalue_id IN ('.implode(",", $arr[1]).')';
```

Then finally use the `$sql`.

```
$main_sql = select * from tbl_product where id IN($sql);
```